# Travis CI Build Fails for android-20 and android-22

Tags: android, travis-ci, android-5.1.1-lollipop

I want to test my code from android-15 to android-23, but unfortunately build fails for android-20 and android-22.

> Error: Invalid --tag default for the selected target.
>
> The command "echo no | android create avd --force -n test -t
>   $ANDROID_TARGET --abi $ANDROID_ABI" failed and exited with 1 during .

travis file :

```
language: android
sudo: false
jdk: oraclejdk7
os:
  - linux
android:
  components:
    - platform-tools
    - tools
    - build-tools-23.0.3
    - android-23
    # Additional components
    - extra
    - extra-google-m2repository
    - extra-android-m2repository
    - extra-android-support
    # Images
    - sys-img-${ANDROID_ABI}-${ANDROID_TARGET}

env:
  matrix:
    - ANDROID_SDKS=android-15 ANDROID_TARGET=android-15 ANDROID_ABI=armeabi-v7a
    - ANDROID_SDKS=android-16 ANDROID_TARGET=android-16 ANDROID_ABI=armeabi-v7a
    - ANDROID_SDKS=android-17 ANDROID_TARGET=android-17 ANDROID_ABI=armeabi-v7a
    - ANDROID_SDKS=android-18 ANDROID_TARGET=android-18 ANDROID_ABI=armeabi-v7a
    - ANDROID_SDKS=android-19 ANDROID_TARGET=android-19 ANDROID_ABI=armeabi-v7a
    - ANDROID_SDKS=android-20 ANDROID_TARGET=android-20 ANDROID_ABI=armeabi-v7a
    - ANDROID_SDKS=android-21 ANDROID_TARGET=android-21 ANDROID_ABI=armeabi-v7a
    - ANDROID_SDKS=android-22 ANDROID_TARGET=android-22 ANDROID_ABI=armeabi-v7a
    - ANDROID_SDKS=android-23 ANDROID_TARGET=android-23 ANDROID_ABI=armeabi-v7a


  global:
      # wait up to 10 minutes for adb to connect to emulator
      - ADB_INSTALL_TIMEOUT=10

cache:
  directories:
    - $HOME/.gradle/caches/2.10
    - $HOME/.gradle/caches/jars-1
    - $HOME/.gradle/daemon
    - $HOME/.gradle/native
    - $HOME/.gradle/wrapper

before_install:
  - chmod +x gradlew

before_script:
  - echo no | android create avd --force -n test -t $ANDROID_TARGET --abi $ANDROID_ABI
  - emulator -avd test -no-skin -no-audio -no-window &

script:
  - android-wait-for-emulator
  - adb devices
  - adb shell setprop dalvik.vm.dexopt-flags v=n,o=v
  - adb shell input keyevent 82 &
  - ./gradlew connectedCheck
```

travis [result](https://travis-ci.org/shgharib/protector/builds/128419030)

How fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Android 20 SDK target is for KitKat4.4 wearables and has a slightly different system image with abi prefix that is causing the error.

Under the #images you can add the image provided by Travis-CI

```
- sys-img-armeabi-v7a-android-wear-20
```

In the android 20 matrix script you will have to add android-wear/armeabi-v7

```
- ANDROID_SDKS=android-20 ANDROID_TARGET=android-20 ANDROID_ABI=android-wear/armeabi-v7a
```

Comment: Thank you, it's working for android-20 but not android-22, how fix it for android-22?

Comment: No problem, I think you just need to add  `android-22` to the `components:` list. The sys image `sys-img-armeabi-v7a-android-22` should be correctly found then.